# Error in running scalar-valued function when different calling method is used

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have this function

```html
CREATE FUNCTION fullName
(
@customer_id int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
SELECT @name = (SELECT name_last + ', ' + name_first FROM DT_CUSTOMERS WHERE customer_id = @customer_id)
RETURN @name
END
```

When I call/run the function with this code, it works:

`SELECT dbo.fullName(356)`

But when I use this method, it gives me the error "Invalid object name 'fullName'" with or without the "dbo." before the function name :

`SELECT * FROM fullName(356)`

Comment: Your function is a **scalar** function - it returns a **single value** - therefore you **cannot** select from it like from a table. If you want to do that, you'd have to rewrite your function to return a **table**

Comment: weird. because it works when my other colleagues use it. with the same code